# Alignment of numbers in exercise environment

Tags: alignment, includegraphics, exercises

I'm trying to adjust the margins for an exercise environment. Neither I nor ChatGPT could figure this one out. I'd like the following:

1. The exercise numbers should be left-aligned with the non-exercise text (that is, the "16" should be left-aligned with the pre-exercise left boundary). I can get it to look good by adjusting the {adjustwidth}{} value, but then it works only for some chapters (e.g., <10 vs >9), and it's kinda hacky. It seems like the aligning is on the exercise number, and so the chapter number is left of that alignment.
2. The Figure should span the regular text boundaries. Now it's text width, but the boundary is too far to the right, while the caption is left-aligned with the text.

I hope the MWE and screenshot are clear. Thanks much in advance for your help and suggestions!

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage[]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\newcommand{\QuestionNB}{\bfseries\thechapter.\arabic{Question}.}

\usepackage{changepage}
\let\oldExercise\Exercise
\let\oldendExercise\endExercise
\renewenvironment{Exercise}{%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1em}{0em}
  \oldExercise}{\oldendExercise\end{adjustwidth}}

\setcounter{chapter}{16}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\section{Exercises}
\begin{Exercise}

  \Question  \lipsum[4]
  
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test4mwe.png}
    \captionof{figure}{\lipsum[4]}}
    
  \lipsum[2]

\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]